# How to store image uri from gallery in database for loading later in Xamarin.Android?

Tags: c#, android, xamarin, xamarin.android

I want to let a user load an image from their gallery:

```
var imageIntent = new Intent();
            imageIntent.SetType("image/*");
            imageIntent.SetAction(Intent.ActionGetContent);
            StartActivityForResult(Intent.CreateChooser(imageIntent, "Select photo"), REQUESTCODE);
```

This works fine: I can use the image in that activity. But I want to store the URI in the database so the image is associated with the object. I use:

```
_recipeImage.SetImageURI(data.Data);
model.ImageUrl = data.Data.ToString();
```

`_recipeImage` is just an image view I'm using to see if I actually got the image correctly for now.

When I save my model to the database I get a string that looks something like:

```
content://com.android.providers.downloads.documents/document/22
```

When the user opens this item later the image should load so I parse the string to a `Uri`. I try and set the image URI as I did before, but no image gets shown.

```
var uri = Android.Net.Uri.Parse(imageUrl);
imageView.SetImageURI(uri);
```

Is there a better/working way to do this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you want to load image directly use URL, it's easier to use some third-party lib, for example [Picasso](http://square.github.io/picasso/).

Since it's a java lib, you can use [Binding Library](https://developer.xamarin.com/guides/android/advanced_topics/binding-a-java-library/binding-a-jar/) to use it in Xamarin.

After adding this lib into your project, you can simply code like this:

```
Picasso.With(this).Load(imageUrl).Into(imageView);
```